# show that x'y' + yz' +x'z' = yz' + x'y'

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need to show that x'y' + yz' +x'z' = yz' + x'y'

My attempt went something like this

x'y' + yz' +x'z' = x'y' + z'(x'+y) = (x'y')'' + z'(x'+y) = (x + y)' + z'(x'+y)

After this point, I'm stuck. Can anyone give me a hint to put me on the right direction?

Comment: This was recently asked at Mathematics Stack Exchange http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1124393/18398 and a link to an answer is there.

Comment: You could take the red pill and try the Laws of Form.

Comment: This question belongs on Math Stack Exchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because cross-posting is not cool. Instead, edit the question on Math.SE and they will reopen your question.

Comment: @CamilStaps  I can't edit the question on Math.SE because 1) I didn't post the question 2) I'm not of a high enough reputation to actually edit anything I didn't post myself.  I'm sorry if you guys feel this belongs on Math.SE, this is a question from a class I'm taking in electronics engineering, so I assumed it was best asked here

Comment: It should be possible suggest an edit, which will be reviewed first.

Comment: What could I suggest? I can't tell the SE world what the OP's work would look like, nor can I tell the world what is confusing the OP. The answer is already in latex there isn't much for me to do. Look at who is asking the question on Math.SE their name is Michael Tseng which is not my handle (Dunka is my handle).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When faced with such problems, I (personally) follow this approach :

```
Step 1 :
```

Rewrite the entire expression so that every term has all the variables.

You have a function of 3 variables x,y and z. So rewrite the expression so it has all of them.

x'y'(z+z') + (x+x')yz' + x(y+y')z'

```
Step 2 :
```

Open the brackets. You might think thats going long, but wait.

x'y'z + x'y'z' +

xyz' + x'yz' +

x'yz' + x'y'z'

I have written them in separate lines to make sure that in the next step, you dont combine the terms from the same bracket again. If you do, you'll get back the original expression.

```
Step 3 :
```

In the final expression you need x'y' and yz'. Identify such terms.

They are ( from step 2) 1st, 2nd and 6th for x'y' and 3rd, 4th and 5th for yz'.

But remember 1st and 2nd are from same brackets (obtained after expansion). Similarly, 3rd and 4th are from same brackets.

So for initial simplification, use only 1 term from each.

In your case, you could use, say, 1st and 6th term for x'y' and 3rd and 5th for yz'.

Rest is just simplification, which should be evident once the above steps are carried out.

Again, one could argue the validity of the steps, or whether its the correct or incorrect approach, I have so far found this to be satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw a K-map you will see that the term x'z' is redundant.

Comment: I know that, but I'm only allowed to use boolean laws. I'll edit the question to include that information.